# Iterate Mapping with object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a variable listUrl like this:

```
   const listUrl: Map<string, {}> = new Map();
```

So then I'm adding some values in this variable:

```
   const obj: { urlComponent: string; changelogComponent: string } = {
                    urlComponent: url,
                    changelogComponent: finalUrl,
                };
  listUrl.set(v.component, obj);
```

So now for example in my listUrl, I've got:

```
Map {
'toto' => { urlComponent:
    'https://toto***',
    changelogComponent:
    'https://git/***/changelog.txt' },
'titi' => { urlComponent:
    'https://toto***',
    changelogComponent:
    'https://git/***/changelog.txt' },
```

Now, I'm trying to iterate into the Mapping but how can I get the urlComponent and changelogComponent during my loop:

```
 listUrl.forEach((test1, test2) => {
        console.log(test1.urlComponent); // don't work -> Property 'urlComponent' does not exist on type '{}'
        console.log(test1.changelogComponent); // don't work -> Property 'changelogCOmponent' does not exist on type '{}'
        console.log(test2); // work
    });
```

Don't understand how can I retrieve value for urlComponent and changelogComponent ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type you defined for your Map is not precise enough: having values of `{}` doesn't give TS enough information. Define the Map as having types of the object with the `urlComponent` etc properties:

```
type ComponentObj = { urlComponent: string; changelogComponent: string };
const listUrl: Map<string, ComponentObj> = new Map();
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the important part

// ...

const obj = {
    urlComponent: url,
    changelogComponent: finalUrl,
};
listUrl.set(v.component, obj);
```

Then you'll be able to iterate over the Map.

Note that there's no need to define a type for a variable you're declaring if TS can detect it automatically - the `obj` doesn't need to be assigned a type explicitly, TS will infer it.

Comment: Oh ok I understand, thank you so much for your help, appreciate it :)